# Definition of a cubic coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, coordinate-systems

I'm looking at "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds" by Frank Warner, and have a question about one of the basic definitions at the beginning of the book. He writes:

*A coordinate system* $(U,\phi)$ *is called cubic if* $\phi(U)$ *is an open cube about the origin in* $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. *A coordinate system is said to be entered at* $m\in U$ *if* $\phi(m)=0$.

Can anyone please explain in pedestrian (i.e. suitable for an undergraduate) terms, what exactly "cubic" means? Could you explicitly give an example? And/or alternative, more concrete definition?

Also, the same question applies to "centered".

Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

So I would take this as $\phi(U)= (a_1,b_1) \times... \times (a_n,b_n)$, where $a_i<0<b_i$ for each $i$ and $b_1-a_1=b_2-a_2=...=b_n-a_n$. So it looks like a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the origin.

Comment: Warner applies this concept in the context of vector fields. Could you give n example of a vector field in a cubic coordinate system?